# Batch fetching from JMS queue

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, messaging

I need to implement the following workflow:

1. Every N milliseconds fetch all available messages from JMS queue, but not more than K items
2. Do some processing
3. Acknowledge all of them once processing is done

I'm interested in how to implement step #1 correctly using JMS.

What I've tried is to:

1. Create a [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) size K
2. In the `onMessage` method of my JMS `MessageListener` put the messages into the `BlockingQueue`.
3. Every N milliseconds drain the `BlockingQueue`, process the messages, and acknowledge them.

It looks fine at glance, but the issue is that if some message is fetched in `onMessage` during processing of the batch then once the batch is done it will be also acked while it is in the `BlockingQueue` and was not processed yet ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568779/can-client-receive-multiple-messages-of-the-queue-before-acknowledging-them/14578272#14578272)). So if my app goes down message will not be processed at all.

What is a better way to implement step #1? Is it something in JMS API or maybe some standard approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JMS doesn't support "batch fetching." Messages have to be fetched/received one at a time. However, work on multiple messages can be batched together using a transacted session.

Also, by using a `MessageListener` implementation you're giving up control of when your application receives messages as the `onMessage` method will be invoked whenever a message is put into the queue.

I recommend you eliminate the `MessageListener` completely. Instead, every N seconds use a transacted `javax.jms.Session` and invoke [`javax.jms.MessageConsumer.receive(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#receive-long-) until it returns `null` (which means the queue is empty) or you have K messages. Then you can process all those messages and invoke [`javax.jms.Session.commit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#commit--) when you're done to commit the transacted session and acknowledge all the messages.

Keep in mind that the larger your batch is the greater the chance is that you'll duplicate work. For example, if you receive K messages and process K - 1 messages before some kind of failure occurs which prevents you from committing the transacted session then those messages will be cancelled back to the queue and potentially redelivered and processed again later.